# How do I set some project references to CopyLocal = false based on metadata?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, metadata

I have two solutions. The first solution outputs assemblies to /bin/Debug. The second solution references the assemblies in that folder and when it builds, outputs to /bin/Debug/AddOn.

How do I prevent the projects in the second solution from copying the assemblies it references in /bin/Debug into /bin/Debug/Addon without editing every single project file to set CopyLocal to False?

I'm trying to solve this problem using a Directory.Build.props that applies to projects within the second solution.

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Reference Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(Reference.FullPath)').Contains('bin/Debug'))">
      <Private>false</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

MSBuild evaluates $(Reference.FullPath) and a few other metadata to "", which means the assemblies get copied anyway.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/arthur-conde/StackOverflow)

Comment: You can easily get the behavior you want following [Thomas's blog](https://thomasfreudenberg.com/archive/2012/11/21/dont-copy-my-referenced-assemblies/), but it will remove all the referenced assemblies even for those you may need in the future development. So i made some changes in my answer, then in the future, if you need some assemblies not in `bin\debug` copied, it can still work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a target which executes after `ResolveAssemblyReferences` target into `AddOn.csproj` like this:

```
  <Target Name="ClearReferenceCopyLocalPaths" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToExclude Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.FullPath)').Contains('bin\Debug'))"/>
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(FilesToExclude)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The `ReferenceCopyLocalPaths` Item is what you need I think. Get some hints from [Don’t copy my referenced assemblies](https://thomasfreudenberg.com/archive/2012/11/21/dont-copy-my-referenced-assemblies/) and [this blog](http://www.codingmurmur.com/2014/02/automatically-embed-copy-local.html). And since you want this script to apply to all projects in the solution, you can add this target script into `Directory.Build.props` and place this file in the `solution folder`.

**In addition**: In your script, I think you should use `bin\Debug` instead of `bin/Debug` in that situation. (Once I use `bin\Debug` in `contains` function it works well, but not work with `bin/Debug` after my test)

Hope it helps :)